# How do I manipulate the Hyper-v WMI Classes and methods

Tags: go, wmi, hyper-v, openstack-nova

Hyper-v is integrated into openstack via the hyper-v wmi interface.The hyper-v wmi interfaces is invoked in the same way as the code in this link shows:
https://github.com/openstack/os-win/blob/master/os_win/utils/baseutils.py

97   vs_man_svc = self._compat_conn.Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService()[0]

Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService is a hyper-v wmi classes:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136940(v=vs.85).aspx.

The question is that the above example is implemented in python, how does the 
golang do this?

Answer (score 0):

WMI is a part of Windows APIs, available through the COM[+] layer,
so there's no real difference in which language you're accessing WMI,
provided that language has a way to access COM[+].

Still, there's a dedicated package to deal with WMI for Go:
[`github.com/StackExchange/wmi`](https://godoc.org/github.com/StackExchange/wmi).

So, after having that package installed, you have a task of discerning calls
to WMI subsystem from the Python code and reimplementing those in terms of that package.

Oh, and studying the results of [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go+wmi) should mostly have you up to speed with this stuff.